# Dividing a SUM with a Count returns false results

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm fairly new to SQL, but it has been going ok until I ran into the following problem. 
What I want is a statement that gets a SUM of the ACCOUNT_COUNT column and than to divide this with the COUNT from IS_TERMINATED column.

I have tried the following so far:

```
SELECT SUM(ACCOUNT_COUNT) / COUNT(IS_TERMINATED) FROM T_APPLICATIONS, V_USERS WHERE RESOURCE_TYPE='A';
```

This returns:

> 1.36714285714285714285714285714285714286E02

While it should return:

> 5.06349206349206349206349206349206349206E00

If I try to get both the SUM and COUNT value seperatly, it returns the correct values

```
SELECT COUNT(IS_TERMINATED) FROM V_USERS;
```

Returns:

> 189

and

```
SELECT SUM(ACCOUNT_COUNT) FROM T_APPLICATIONS WHERE RESOURCE_TYPE='A';
```

returns:

> 957

```
957 / 189 = 5.06349206349206349206349206349206349206E00
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Think you try to join 2 tables? If yes it is wrong: try `SELECT SUM(ACCOUNT_COUNT), COUNT(IS_TERMINATED) , SUM(ACCOUNT_COUNT) / COUNT(IS_TERMINATED) FROM T_APPLICATIONS, V_USERS WHERE RESOURCE_TYPE='A';
` to see wich values are calculated.

Comment: What is the sum of IS_TERMINATED where RESOURCE_TYPE = 'A' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to join your tables.

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(ACCOUNT_COUNT) / COUNT(IS_TERMINATED) 
FROM T_APPLICATIONS x inner join V_USERS v ON x.ID = v.ID
 WHERE RESOURCE_TYPE='A';
```

And if you dont have a key to join then try this:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT SUM(ACCOUNT_COUNT) FROM T_APPLICATIONS WHERE RESOURCE_TYPE='A') /
  (SELECT COUNT(IS_TERMINATED) FROM V_USERS)
```

Comment: There are no keys to join, but the 2nd answer worked wonders! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You get the correct values in different querys, but in the incorrect query, you join the two tables (basically, you cross join them).

You can see it go wrong if you select the sum and count separately, but within your first query:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(ACCOUNT_COUNT), 
  COUNT(IS_TERMINATED) 
FROM 
  T_APPLICATIONS, V_USERS WHERE RESOURCE_TYPE='A';
```

Now, to fix it, just embed the two subqueries in a select:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT SUM(ACCOUNT_COUNT) FROM T_APPLICATIONS WHERE RESOURCE_TYPE='A') /
  (SELECT COUNT(IS_TERMINATED) FROM V_USERS)
```